# Standard deviation showing up as NA in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

When I do the following:

```
data_control %>%
  group_by(politics, partner_politics) %>%
  summarize(pd_sent_amount = mean(as.numeric(pd_sent_amount)),
            n = n(),
            pd_sent_amount_sd =  sd(as.numeric(pd_sent_amount), na.rm = T)
           )
```

I get the current output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   politics [?]
  politics   partner_politics pd_sent_amount     n pd_sent_amount_sd
  <fct>      <fct>                     <dbl> <int>             <dbl>
1 Democrat   Democrat                  0.598    76                NA
2 Democrat   Republican                0.479    34                NA
3 Republican Democrat                  0.404    34                NA
4 Republican Republican                0.404    70                NA
```

Not sure why the standard deviation calculations are coming up NA as I can calculate them manually by group, e.g.:

```
test = subset(data_control, politics == "Democrat" & partner_politics == "Democrat")
with(test, sd(pd_sent_amount) / sqrt(nrow(test)))

> with(test, sd(pd_sent_amount) / sqrt(nrow(test)))
[1] 0.05008275
```

Here's a dput of a sample of the data:

```
structure(list(politics = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Democrat", "Republican"
), class = "factor"), partner_politics = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Democrat", 
"Republican"), class = "factor"), pd_sent_amount = c(0.2, 0, 
0.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 
1, 1, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.5, 1)), row.names = 5:34, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you can't use this *exact* data, you can probably figure out a way to mimic the issue with dummy data

Comment: Why did you override `na.rm` in `sd()` but not `mean()`? I’m just curious because It’s calling the same column so if the default works for `mean()` it should mean there aren’t any `NA` values in the vector. `sd()` and `mean()` seem to behave similarly and that is the only difference I see in the call to each.

Comment: You get the same issue with or without na.rm.  I added that in last second in case someone suspected I needed to remove na's.  @camille, I added in some sample data

Comment: I had another thought... I think that because the `mean` column has the same name and the `sd` call is coming after, it is actually referencing the summarized version of pd_sent_amount. Try giving the summarized version a new name such as pd_sent_amount_mean.

Comment: Genius, @Wil!  That's it!  I've been at this for hours, and couldn't figure it out.  Case closed.   Feel free to write up as an answer.

Comment: @Parseltongue answer below. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `sd()` is referencing the in-place mutation (summarization) of pd_sent_amount. Give the summarized column a new name.

```r
data_control %>%
  group_by(politics, partner_politics) %>%
  summarize(pd_sent_amount_mean = mean(as.numeric(pd_sent_amount)),
            n = n(),
            pd_sent_amount_sd =  sd(as.numeric(pd_sent_amount), na.rm = T)
           )
```

The fourth example given [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) on the dplyr website mentions that "newly created summaries immediately overwrite existing variables", and the example is actually the same case as yours with sequential calls to `mean()` and `sd()`.